# AWS lambda C# core CultureInfo ToString issue

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, cultureinfo

I am trying to change the format of ToLongDateString to be in my local culture (da-DK).
For now I am doing the following, and if it can be done in a better way, then it will be very appreciated:

```
CultureInfo cCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
string dateTimeStr = freeSeat.FreeDate.ToLongDateString().ToString(cCulture);
```

This works as expected on my local development environment, but when I deploy it to AWS lambda, I just get the English culture format. I am pretty sure the issue is that in AWS the C# core code is running on Linux.

I hope someone can give me some input how to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ToLongDateString` method returns a string formatted according to the current thread culture. Calling `ToString` method later is useless.

Do it like this:

```
CultureInfo cCulture = new CultureInfo("da-DK");
string format = cCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern;
string dateTimeStr = freeSeat.FreeDate.ToString(format, cCulture);
```